# Check if string contains certain characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to check if the login being inserted into employee table is given in a certain format, which is: the first letter is strictly given - x, then 5 letters and two numbers =>  xlogin00.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_login
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF login ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    xlogin00 employee.login%TYPE;
    prefix VARCHAR2(1);
    name VARCHAR2(5);
    number VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
xlogin00 := :new.login;
prefix := substr(xlogin00,1,1);
name := substr(xlogin00,2,5);
number := substr(xlogin00,7,2);
if(LENGTH(xlogin00) != 8) then
    Raise_Application_Error (-20203, 'Error');
end if;
if(prefix != 'x') then
    Raise_Application_Error (-20204, 'Error');
end if;
if NOT REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[^a-z]') then
    Raise_Application_Error (-20204, 'Error');
end if;
if NOT REGEXP_LIKE(number, '[^0-9]') then
    Raise_Application_Error (-20204, 'Error');
end if;
END;
```

The only thing that seems to work in my code is `if(prefix != 'x')`. Other stuff doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain what the correct format is, with examples of both correct and incorrect values.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of that with one check:

```
IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(:new.login, '^x[a-z]{5}\d\d$') THEN
    Raise_Application_Error (-20204, 'Error');
```

Note that you had also your boolean logic reversed: in both last tests you have a double negation (`NOT` in the `IF` and `[^...]` in the regex).

Note that in the proposed regex the `^` and `$` are needed to make sure the match is with the complete login value, not just a substring.

Comment: And if you need to allow upper case also, then use REGEXP_LIKE( ..., 'i') (with a third parameter which indicates case insensitive patern matching). If instead the first letter must be lower-case x, but the other letters can be upper- or lower-case, then in the match pattern itself, where Gordon has [a-z], write [a-zA-Z] instead.